# How to update value in template Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I use Angularjs on page for displaying numbers of notes:

```
<span ng-hide="currentCount.messages <= 0">{{currentCount.messages}}</span>
```

The value `currentCount.messages` is got from response AJAX in controller.
Problem is that when I do reflesh browser page I see text `{{currentCount.messages}}` temporarily.

I tried to define in top controller:  `$scope.currentCount.messages = 0;` but it did not help me.

Comment: Does "temply" mean that the placeholder is shown for a short time while the page is loading, and you don't want that?

Comment: read up  on how `ng-cloak` works

Comment: Either add a spinner/loader that will show (ng-show="loading") while the content hides (ng-hide="loading") while loading the data, just set $scope.loading to true/false before/after the ajax. Or look into https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: Sorry, `temporarily`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<span ng-hide="currentCount.messages <= 0" ng-bind="currentCount.messages"></span>
```

Using ng-bind accomplishes the same thing, but you won't see the template string in the page before the angular finishes rendering.

Comment: Thanks It work, but below this code also: `ng-class="{0:'hide'}[currentCount.messages]"` and it takes value from init variable `currentCount.messages`, not after  AJAX response, so I get wrong class `hide` then